# Wireshark-like software for capturing Bluetooth communication data?

Tags: bluetooth

Is there any Wireshark-like software for capturing Bluetooth communication data in iOS ?

I have a smart bracelet paired up with iPhone 5s. I would like to know how does the data communicating. Is it possible?

If the software must be installed in PC, how can I pick up the data between phone and bracelet?

Requirements:

- capture Bluetooth communication data (preferably in Wireshark-readable format)
- GUI is optional (command line is fine)
- either run on iOS / PC / Mac

For viewing (if the output is only viewable via the software, as Wireshark already provided the features below):

- able to read packet data
- able to filter the source and destination
- able to search by keywords

*p.s. the device is running via Bluetooth LE.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wireshark can actually do this

Wireshark can capture bluetooth packets using something like the [Ubertooth One](http://greatscottgadgets.com/ubertoothone/) with the [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) library.

> You can capture Bluetooth traffic to or from your machine on Linux in Wireshark with libpcap 0.9.6 and later, if the kernel includes the BlueZ Bluetooth stack; starting with the 2.4.6 kernel, the BlueZ stack was incorporated into the mainline kernel.

Check out the [Wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth) for setup information.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switched platform, using Android 5.0's built-in Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log. Then, I use `adb` to transfer the log and open the log in Wireshark to review the packet content in Mac / PC.